# Saving web api consumed piece of data throughout an Angular application

Tags: angular, typescript

I have create a new angular 4 project using the angular cli. I have it setup to talk to a web api which has a method that returns the windows username of the current user. I would like to call the api to get the windows username the least amount as possible throughout the application. There are a lot of pages in the application and the user does not have to go to one single page every time they want to access the application.

Questions

1. Where is the best place to make the API call inside the angular application so I only need to call the web api once?
2. What is the best way to store the windows username so it does not expire during their time on the application?

Comment: You can take a look at the ngrx/store (https://github.com/ngrx/platform), it is a state management for Angular applications, inspired by Redux. This is not the only way to do this, not even the easier, but is an option (using a global state container for your app).

Comment: @ChristianBenseler I will take a look at. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use a service that will fetch the username from Windows and save it in [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).
2. Register that service globally by adding it to the providers array of your root module
3. Inject the service into any component that needs to know the username.
4. When a component calls `service.getUsername()`, the method will first look for it in local storage and return it from there.